# How to download file that has space in its name?

Tags: iis, lamp

In my virtual directory, I have many mp3 files, there are space or Chinese characters. How do I allow visitors to download them?

For example:
There's no problem when downloading `www.myWebsite.com/virtualDirectory/songNameSimple.mp3`

But if the song name has space in it, it's replaced by %20, thus return 404 error.

I'm curious about solution in both iis and lamp, although maybe the solution is the same.

Thanks

Comment: Catch the request server side and replace the %20 with a space.

Comment: @BobThomas There's also Chinese characters...

Comment: Cant you use the same solution for that but then check it against puny code or another way to identify Chinese characters

Comment: @BobThomas How do I modify the query? Say the user type in www.myWebsite.com/song%20name.mp3, where do I modify it if I'm using IIS?

Comment: hmm sorry no experience with IIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server is handling this automatically, it was working for me at the beginning due to something else.